# Hide submenu when different submenu is opened

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have created this menu.
I want that you can only open one submenu at the time. So if you open the menu for club first and then the menu for profile, the club menu should automatically close. How can this be achieved?

Additionally: It would also be great if all submenus close when closing the hamburger in the top right corner. so that if you reopen the hamburger, the menus are all hidden if that makes any sense...
https://codepen.io/bvonr/pen/oNwOjgp

```js
(function () {
  var change = document.querySelector(".burger-container"),
    box = document.querySelector(".mobilenavigation"),
    hider = document.querySelector(".bodyandfooter");

  change.onclick = function () {
    change.classList.toggle("menu-opened");
    box.classList.toggle("menu-opened");
    hider.classList.toggle("menu-opened");
  };
})();

$(".secondLayer > .plus-button > ul").parent().parent().addClass("hasChildren");

$(".secondLayer").click(function () {
  $(this).find(".plus-button").toggleClass("open");
  $(this).find(".plus-button").parent().parent().toggleClass("expand");
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: brown;
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 50px;
}
.mobilenavigation {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.burger-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: auto;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
#burger {
  width: 18px;
  height: 8px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: -4px auto 0;
  top: 50%;
}
.bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
.bar.topBar {
  transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
}
.bar.btmBar {
  transform: translateY(6px) rotate(0deg);
}
.burger-container.menu-opened {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.burger-container.menu-opened #burger .bar {
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
.burger-container.menu-opened #burger .bar.topBar {
  transform: translateY(4px) rotate(45deg);
}
.burger-container.menu-opened #burger .bar.btmBar {
  transform: translateY(3px) rotate(-45deg);
}
.mobilenavigation.menu-opened {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  height: calc(100vh - 80px);
  width: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.plus-button {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
}
.plus-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #24603c;
  border-radius: 0.75em;
  transition: 0.3s;
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
  top: -4px;
}
.plus-icon:before {
  width: 20px;
  height: 3px;
  border-radius: 0.75em;
  transition: 0.3s;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  transform-origin: 10px center;
  transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 90deg);
  background-color: #24603c;
}
.open.plus-button .plus-icon:before {
  transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 90deg);
}
.hasChildren .plus-button {
  display: block;
}
.menulist {
  display: none;
}
.secondLayer {
  float: right;
}
.expand > .menulist {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  <div class="mobilenavigation menu-opened">
    <div class="navbar">
      <ul class="menuliste">
        <li class="menuli1">
          <a href="">CLUB</a>
          <div class="secondLayer">
            <div class="plus-button">
              <div class="plus-icon"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <ul class="menulist">
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="#">Download</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="#">CLUB-KALENDER</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="#">RAUMBELEGUNG</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="#">FORUM</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menuli1">
          <a href="#">profile</a>
          <div class="secondLayer">
            <div class="plus-button">
              <div class="plus-icon"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <ul class="menulist">
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="#">PROFIL</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="#">Freigaben</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="#">ARTIKEL</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="#">GRUPPENLEITER</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="burger-container menu-opened">
    <div id="burger">
      <div class="bar topBar"></div>
      <div class="bar btmBar"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove all expand and open before toggling if they are not belonging to this accordion

```
$(".secondLayer").click(function () {
  const $thisPlus = $(this).find(".plus-button")
  const $thisLiContainer = $(this).find(".plus-button").closest("li");
  $(".open").not($thisPlus).removeClass("open");
  $(".expand").not($thisLiContainer).removeClass("expand");
  $thisPlus.toggleClass("open");
  $thisLiContainer.toggleClass("expand");
});
```

```js
(function () {
  var change = document.querySelector(".burger-container"),
    box = document.querySelector(".mobilenavigation"),
    hider = document.querySelector(".bodyandfooter");

  change.onclick = function () {
    change.classList.toggle("menu-opened");
    box.classList.toggle("menu-opened");
    hider.classList.toggle("menu-opened");
  };
})();

$(".secondLayer > .plus-button > ul").closest("li").addClass("hasChildren");

$(".secondLayer").click(function () {
  const $thisPlus = $(this).find(".plus-button")
  const $thisLiContainer = $(this).find(".plus-button").closest("li");
  $(".open").not($thisPlus).removeClass("open");
  $(".expand").not($thisLiContainer).removeClass("expand");
  $thisPlus.toggleClass("open");
  $thisLiContainer.toggleClass("expand");
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: brown;
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 50px;
}
.mobilenavigation {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.burger-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: auto;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
#burger {
  width: 18px;
  height: 8px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: -4px auto 0;
  top: 50%;
}
.bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
.bar.topBar {
  transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
}
.bar.btmBar {
  transform: translateY(6px) rotate(0deg);
}
.burger-container.menu-opened {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.burger-container.menu-opened #burger .bar {
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
.burger-container.menu-opened #burger .bar.topBar {
  transform: translateY(4px) rotate(45deg);
}
.burger-container.menu-opened #burger .bar.btmBar {
  transform: translateY(3px) rotate(-45deg);
}
.mobilenavigation.menu-opened {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  height: calc(100vh - 80px);
  width: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.plus-button {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
}
.plus-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #24603c;
  border-radius: 0.75em;
  transition: 0.3s;
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
  top: -4px;
}
.plus-icon:before {
  width: 20px;
  height: 3px;
  border-radius: 0.75em;
  transition: 0.3s;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  transform-origin: 10px center;
  transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 90deg);
  background-color: #24603c;
}
.open.plus-button .plus-icon:before {
  transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 90deg);
}
.hasChildren .plus-button {
  display: block;
}
.menulist {
  display: none;
}
.secondLayer {
  float: right;
}
.expand > .menulist {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  <div class="mobilenavigation menu-opened">
    <div class="navbar">
      <ul class="menuliste">
        <li class="menuli1">
          <a href="">CLUB</a>
          <div class="secondLayer">
            <div class="plus-button">
              <div class="plus-icon"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <ul class="menulist">
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="#">Download</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="#">CLUB-KALENDER</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="#">RAUMBELEGUNG</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="#">FORUM</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menuli1">
          <a href="#">profile</a>
          <div class="secondLayer">
            <div class="plus-button">
              <div class="plus-icon"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <ul class="menulist">
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="#">PROFIL</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="#">Freigaben</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="#">ARTIKEL</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="#">GRUPPENLEITER</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="burger-container menu-opened">
    <div id="burger">
      <div class="bar topBar"></div>
      <div class="bar btmBar"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I had thought about the same solution, however, with this approach, I am not able to close the submenus by pressing the minus buttons. Is there any possibility to keep this functionality?

Comment: No worries! I appreciate your help

Comment: Ok, fixed. Just have to use .not(thisThing)

Comment: I changed parent.parent to closest('li')  - it is shorter and more descriptive